# Error: 'schema should be object or boolean' in ajv.addSchema

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to refactor some JSONSchema checks to include one schema in another using a `$ref` include.

As I'm using AJV for validation of the schemas, I've been trying to use the `addSchema` function to load the two schemas but I keep getting the error `schema should be object or boolean` but as far as I know I've defined the schema correctly.

My JS code reads as:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');
var ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: 'true', verbose: 'true' });
ajv.addMetaSchema(require('ajv/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-06.json'));
ajv.addSchema('../../schema/sport_schema/tennis_sport_schema.json', 'tennis_sport_schema.json');
ajv.addSchema('../../schema/sport_schema/tennis_event_schema.json', 'tennis_event_schema.json');
```

The schema `tennis_sport_schema.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "title": "Tennis Sport endpoint schema",
    "description": "The Tennis Sport endpoint for Sport API",
    "required": ["offset", "limit", "hasNext", "hasPrevious", "items"],
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "offset": {
            "type": "number",
            "const": 0
        },
        "limit": {
            "type": "number",
            "const": 20
        },
        "hasNext": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "const": true
        },
        "hasPrevious": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "const": false
        },
        "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "maxItems": 20,
            "items": {
                "$ref": "tennis_event_schema.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error output is:

```
mocha "test/sport_tests/tennis_schema.js"

/Users/framps01/Workspace/sport-store-test-framework/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js:300
    throw new Error('schema should be object or boolean');
    ^

Error: schema should be object or boolean
at Ajv._addSchema (/Users/framps01/Workspace/sport-store-test-framework/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js:300:15)
at Ajv.addSchema (/Users/framps01/Workspace/sport-store-test-framework/node_modules/ajv/lib/ajv.js:136:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/framps01/Workspace/sport-store-test-framework/test/sport_tests/tennis_schema.js:4:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at /Users/framps01/Workspace/sport-store-test-framework/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:250:27
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/framps01/Workspace/sport-store-test-framework/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:247:14)
at Mocha.run (/Users/framps01/Workspace/sport-store-test-framework/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:576:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/framps01/Workspace/sport-store-test-framework/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:637:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Can any one point me to where I'm going wrong? `tennis_sport_schema.json` is defined as an 'object' so not sure why the error is being thrown to suggest it isnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `addSchema` needs to be an object, not a path to a json file.

`.addSchema(Array<Object>|Object schema [, String key]) -> Ajv`

[source](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#addschemaarrayobjectobject-schema--string-key---ajv)

so that would be:

```
let obj = {"$id": "mySuperSchema"}; //inc the rest of your json schema object.
ajv.addSchema(obj, 'mySuperSchema');
```

Alternatvily, it accepts an array of schema objects, assuming the $id is set in them correctly (second agument is then ignored).

Comment: Thanks @Relequestual! I'd looked through the docs on `ajv` but got myself down a rabbithole in assuming the problem was within the json file rather than the way I was trying to parse the file itself!

I've altered the script to require the files into variables, then passed the variable names into the `addSchema` call and that seems to be working. Thank you!